# Best practices for continually saving data in windows RT

Tags: c#, windows-8, winrt-xaml

I'm working on a windows RT app that allows the user to input some various data. Mostly integers and some strings that relate to a character. Things like: name, strength, dexterity, etc.

What I'd like to see is each character save to its own file, and any change made immediately save into that character's file so that if the app ends the data is there.

On load, I'd like to populate a screen with "New" and the characters found in the folder. Currently I'm focusing on making a single character load and update the file appropriately.

My thoughts were to go through the roaming data here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/apps/hh700362.aspx  but this would involve loading each bit from the container into a variable separately on load and updating it twice (variable and roaming data) each time.

I looked into just loading them as XML and saving the changes like example 3 in this http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/XML-API-Scenario-Sample-42ce708b though I didn't find an easy way to map and XML file into a template for a character using C#.

Ideally, saving XML files to a roaming data thing would be nice for multiple devices, and I could find a way to load an XML file into a template for on load, but I'm unsure if this is possible.

What is the best way to do something like this and is the above thought possible?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the amount of data, you may be able to just use [Application or Roaming Settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464917.aspx#app_settings).  Both have limitations on data size and type, but if it's just a few strings and integers, it may be good enough.  You could create [application data containers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdatacontainer.aspx) for each character and [write all of the properties atomically](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdatacompositevalue.aspx).

Alternatively, use local/roaming files, but be aware that there is also a quota for roaming data, so you may need to determine just how much data the app might sending.  Note too that roaming data has latency and may never sync (for instance if quota is exceeded).   If you do need it for multiple devices and there's a lot of data or you need it more reliably synced, the next step up would be the cloud (and you could use [Windows Azure Mobile Services](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/home/scenarios/mobile-services/) or other storage in Azure).

Not knowing the specifics of your application or the prioritization of requirements, I would probably start with [Local](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464917.aspx#Local_application_data) or [Roaming Application Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464917.aspx#roaming_app_data), and I'm a big fan of the ease of use of [JSON.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/) for serialization, and it's easily added to your solution via NuGet. If you use local files and build just a little bit of an abstraction layer, it won't be hard to later move those files to the cloud, if your app grows in size or usage.